# ASP.NET MVC App - AWS Load Balancer Redirect Http to Https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently created a web application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and set up an EC2 Classic Load Balancer to redirect HTTP urls to HTTPS.  Currently, I can access my site with either HTTP or HTTPS, but I want any request to automatically send it to HTTPS.  I developed and deployed my ASP.NET MVC application from Visual Studio 2015 using AWS Toolkit (otherwise, all of the website functionality has been setup on AWS).  I am very new to AWS altogether and after looking through a number of posts about this, have been unable to figure out a way to force a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.  I looked at this site https://oanhnn.github.io/2016-02-29/how-to-force-https-behind-aws-elb.html but was not sure how to implement what was discussed.  If anyone knows how to do this or knows of good documentation to look at for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to:

1. Install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads) on your Windows Server.
2. Add the following `<rewrite>` section to your Web.config file:

**Web.config**

---

```
<configuration>

  ...

  <system.webServer>

    ...

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the issue